# joining tables with diff number fo columns

Tags: mysql

I am currently working on some embedded sql queries for a local site. And I am running into a confusion. I need to do this "Ask the user for a manufacturer. Print the specifications of all products by that manufacturer. That is print the model number, product-type, and all the attributes of whichever relation is appropriate for that type."

I tried the following query

```
(SELECT * FROM product NATURAL JOIN pc WHERE maker = '$m') 
union (SELECT * FROM product NATURAL JOIN printer WHERE maker = '$m') 
union (SELECT * FROM product NATURAL JOIN laptop WHERE maker = '$m');
```

But the problem arises that each table (pc, laptop, printer) do not have the same columns. I think it will be fine for my problem to just fill in null values if the table does not contain that column. I am trying to just merge all the tables and columns into one super table and display that to the user. Then I also would like to try and order the big table by the product types. Which I think i'll just ass a ORDER BY at the end of the query. So my question is how can I join these tables?

Relations:

```
Product(maker, model, type (laptop, printer, pc))
Printer(model, color (0,1), type(ink-jet, laser), price)
Laptop(model, speed, ram, hd, screen, price)
Pc(model, speed, ram hd, price)
```

Comment: Please don't [repeat tags in the title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/167443)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at "SQL table alias" to add columns to the table with fewer columns. Or you can enter nulls in aswell like:

```
Select Col1, Col2, Col3 from Table1
Union
Select Col1, Null as Col2, Null as Col3 from Table2
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use UNION to do the job.  Simply make all the SELECT lists same names and same types like this:

```
SELECT (a,b) FROM TABLE TableB NATURAL JOIN (

    SELECT a,b,c, NULL as d from TableC
    UNION
    SELECT a,b,NULL as c, d from TableD

) AS u ON u.b = TableB.b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just select NULL values for the non-existing fields.

```
(SELECT maker,pc.model,p.model,price,NULL AS color,speed,pc.type,pc.type,ram,hd,NULL AS screen
  FROM product p NATURAL JOIN pc WHERE maker = '$m') 
UNION 
(SELECT maker,printer.model,p.model,price,color,NULL AS speed,printer.type,p.type,NULL AS ram,NULL AS hd,NULL AS screen
  FROM product p NATURAL JOIN printer WHERE maker = '$m') 
UNION
(SELECT maker,laptop.model,p.model,price,NULL AS color,speed,laptop.type,laptop.type,ram,hd,screen
  FROM product p NATURAL JOIN laptop WHERE maker = '$m');
```

Comment: My MySQL does not like this syntax but this does help, I think I can get it.

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL,speed,q.type,p.type,ram,hd,NULL AS screen   FROM product p NATURAL JOIN pc ' at line 1

Comment: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'q.type' in 'field list'.

Comment: This works well to get a table without the makers. How might i modify this to add a maker column in? "(SELECT model, speed, ram, hd, price, screen, NULL as color, NULL as type FROM laptop) union (SELECT model, speed, ram, hd, price, NULL as screen, NULL as color, NULL as type FROM pc) union (SELECT model, NULL as speed, NULL as ram, NULL as hd, price, NULL as screen, color, type FROM printer);"

Comment: Try now. And feel free to debug yourself if it still doesn't work. ;-)

Comment: I'm sure you can figure that one out yourself.

Answer (score -1):

I think you mean to be using the join keyword, rather than the union keyword.

Have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html